# Correctly positioning a QR code image in an HTML invoice template

Tags: html, css, margins

"I am working on creating an HTML template for an invoice and am having some difficulty placing the QR code image in the correct location. Specifically, I want the QR code image to appear directly under the invoice information table, but it is not appearing in the desired location.

```css
  table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 10px auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #1e2b40;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 6px;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.contact-info {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: right;
  margin: 1px auto;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.contact-info ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.qr-code {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.srs.logo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.items-table {
  float: left;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.items-table th,
.items-table td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 6px;
```

```html
<header>
  <!-- header content goes here -->

  <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mwNaPe8w4Bxn7mkXivmI2dqcwBg4_aog" alt="srs-logo" />

  <div class="contact-info" style="list-style-type: none">
    <ul>
      <li>SARL RO SOLUTION</li>
      <li>RC: RC:</li>
      <li>NIF: NIF</li>
      <li>AI: AI</li>
      <li>Phone: Phone:</li>
      <li>Email: info@company.com</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</header>

<hr style="margin-top: 100px;">

<!-- rest of the page content goes here -->


<table style="float: left;">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="center bold">Customer Information</td>
    <tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Customer Name:</td>
        <td>&lt;&lt;[Customer Name]&gt;&gt;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Customer Address:</td>
        <td>&lt;&lt;[Customer Address]&gt;&gt;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Customer NIF:</td>
        <td>&lt;&lt;[Customer NIF]&gt;&gt;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Customer RC:</td>
        <td>&lt;&lt;[Customer RC]&gt;&gt;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Customer AI:</td>
        <td>&lt;&lt;[Customer AI]&gt;&gt;</td>
        <tr>
          <td>Telephone:</td>
          <td>&lt;&lt;[Company AI]&gt;&gt;</td>
        </tr>
</table>


<table style="float: right; margin: 0 auto">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="center bold">Invoice Information</td>
    <tr>
      <td>Invoice Date:</td>
      <td>&lt;&lt;[Invoice Date]&gt;&gt;</td>
      <tr>
        <td>Invoice ID:</td>
        <td>&lt;&lt;[Invoice ID]&gt;&gt;</td>
      </tr>
</table>


<br style="clear: both;">

<img src="<<[Invoice Date]>>" alt="qr-code">


<br style="clear: both;">
<hr>


<table style="float: left;">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="1" class="center bold">Related Sales</td>
    <td colspan="" class="center bold">Invoice Information</td>
</table>

<br style="clear: both;">

<hr>

<table class="items-table">


  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item description</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <p class="startifend">&lt;&lt;Start:[invoice_key].[Related invoice_items]&gt;&gt;</p>
    <tr>
      <td>&lt;&lt;[description]&gt;&gt;</td>
      <td>&lt;&lt;[quantity]&gt;&gt;</td>
      <td>&lt;&lt;[unit_price]&gt;&gt;</td>
      <td>&lt;&lt;[total_price]&gt;&gt;</td>
    </tr>
    <p class="startifend">&lt;&lt;End&gt;&gt;</p>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br style="clear: both;">
<hr>
```

Comment: Wouldn't the simplest solution be to add another row to that table and place the QR code in that row? 
Otherwise you'd have to look at `flex` or `grid` to create a layout for your page that can contain the tables and qr codes in the same column.

Comment: Hello kokodo, thank you for your suggestion. As a beginner with HTML, I am still learning the different layout options and trying to figure out which one would work best for my needs. I had considered adding another row to the table and placing the QR code in that row, but I wasn't sure if it would be possible to specify the size of the QR code within the table using the style attribute. I haven't tested the output yet, so I'm unsure how it would look. I appreciate your guidance, it seems adding an extra row would solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to presume you have a good reason for using tables over grid/flexbox.

A couple of issues to note. Firstly, be very care to always close your `<tr>` tags there were many unclosed tags through the code which I've corrected in the below snippet.

Secondly, the behaviour of the QR `img` tag was completely correct in your example and it was rendering where it should have been. In order to achieve the desired outcome, you want to put your Customer Information and Invoice Information tables inside a parent table.

In short:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> <!-- Customer Information Table --> </td>
        <td> <!-- Invoice Information Table --> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This will allow you to but the QR `img` directly underneath the Invoice Information Table inside the same `<td>` tag.

```css
  table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 10px auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #1e2b40;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 6px;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.contact-info {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: right;
  margin: 1px auto;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.contact-info ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.qr-code {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.srs.logo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.items-table {
  float: left;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.items-table th,
.items-table td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 6px;
```

```html
<header>
  <!-- header content goes here -->

  <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mwNaPe8w4Bxn7mkXivmI2dqcwBg4_aog" alt="srs-logo" />

  <div class="contact-info" style="list-style-type: none">
    <ul>
      <li>SARL RO SOLUTION</li>
      <li>RC: RC:</li>
      <li>NIF: NIF</li>
      <li>AI: AI</li>
      <li>Phone: Phone:</li>
      <li>Email: info@company.com</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</header>

<hr style="margin-top: 100px;">

<!-- rest of the page content goes here -->

<table style="border:0; width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="border:0; vertical-align:top">
      <table style="float:left;margin:0">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="center bold">Customer Information</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Customer Name:</td>
          <td>&lt;&lt;[Customer Name]&gt;&gt;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Customer Address:</td>
          <td>&lt;&lt;[Customer Address]&gt;&gt;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Customer NIF:</td>
          <td>&lt;&lt;[Customer NIF]&gt;&gt;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Customer RC:</td>
          <td>&lt;&lt;[Customer RC]&gt;&gt;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Customer AI:</td>
          <td>&lt;&lt;[Customer AI]&gt;&gt;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Telephone:</td>
          <td>&lt;&lt;[Company AI]&gt;&gt;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td style="border:0; vertical-align:top;text-align:right;">

      <table style="float:right;">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="center bold">Invoice Information</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Invoice Date:</td>
          <td>&lt;&lt;[Invoice Date]&gt;&gt;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Invoice ID:</td>
          <td>&lt;&lt;[Invoice ID]&gt;&gt;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br style="clear:both;">
      <img src="<<[Invoice Date]>>" alt="qr-code">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>





<br style="clear: both;">
<hr>


<table style="float: left;">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="1" class="center bold">Related Sales</td>
    <td colspan="" class="center bold">Invoice Information</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br style="clear: both;">

<hr>

<table class="items-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item description</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <p class="startifend">&lt;&lt;Start:[invoice_key].[Related invoice_items]&gt;&gt;</p>
    <tr>
      <td>&lt;&lt;[description]&gt;&gt;</td>
      <td>&lt;&lt;[quantity]&gt;&gt;</td>
      <td>&lt;&lt;[unit_price]&gt;&gt;</td>
      <td>&lt;&lt;[total_price]&gt;&gt;</td>
    </tr>
    <p class="startifend">&lt;&lt;End&gt;&gt;</p>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br style="clear: both;">
<hr>
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance and guidance. I appreciate your help in improving the code and providing a solution to the issue with the QR code image. Your suggestion to use a parent table to control the layout of the tables and the image was very helpful, and I will make sure to keep it in mind for future projects. Thank you again for your time and expertise. Btw how can I cath at a glance open <tr> tags?

Comment: If you're using a good IDE (I use VSCode) you should be able to click on the opening tag and the editor will highlight the closing tag. If no highlighted tag, then it's missing. Correct indentation will show you where they are missing!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, added a container to the tables and applied flex box. Remove the margin from the table selector, if you want the tables to go to the left and right edges.

```
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between;">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="center bold">Customer Information</td>
    <tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Customer Name:</td>
        <td>&lt;&lt;[Customer Name]&gt;&gt;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Customer Address:</td>
        <td>&lt;&lt;[Customer Address]&gt;&gt;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Customer NIF:</td>
        <td>&lt;&lt;[Customer NIF]&gt;&gt;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Customer RC:</td>
        <td>&lt;&lt;[Customer RC]&gt;&gt;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Customer AI:</td>
        <td>&lt;&lt;[Customer AI]&gt;&gt;</td>
        <tr>
          <td>Telephone:</td>
          <td>&lt;&lt;[Company AI]&gt;&gt;</td>
        </tr>
</table>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="center bold">Invoice Information</td>
    <tr>
      <td>Invoice Date:</td>
      <td>&lt;&lt;[Invoice Date]&gt;&gt;</td>
      <tr>
        <td>Invoice ID:</td>
        <td>&lt;&lt;[Invoice ID]&gt;&gt;</td>
      </tr>
</table>

</div>

<img style="float:right;" src="<<[Invoice Date]>>" alt="qr-code">
```